# I'm trying to set lines on JPanel on JFrame as standard

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I've got some lines (tablature for music writing) and I'm trying to set them so that the lines show up as standard with the JPanel. I've created this class and tried to create a new instance at runtime, but drawing blanks. I've tried a bunch of things and wanted to create my own method but I might just end up using paint(), if that's easier? What do you think?

```
public class Lines extends JPanel {

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setColor(Color.black);

    g.drawLine(20, 50, 1200, 50);
    g.drawLine(20, 60, 1200, 60);
    g.drawLine(20, 70, 1200, 70);
    g.drawLine(20, 80, 1200, 80);
    g.drawLine(20, 90, 1200, 90);

    g.drawLine(20, 140, 1200, 140);
    g.drawLine(20, 150, 1200, 150);
    g.drawLine(20, 160, 1200, 160);
    g.drawLine(20, 170, 1200, 170);
    g.drawLine(20, 180, 1200, 180);

    g.drawLine(20, 230, 1200, 230);
    g.drawLine(20, 240, 1200, 240);
    g.drawLine(20, 250, 1200, 250);
    g.drawLine(20, 260, 1200, 260);
    g.drawLine(20, 270, 1200, 270);
}
}
```

and I'm trying to create a new instance here;

```
class panelControls extends JPanel {

    private GUIPanel panel;
    private Lines lines;


    public panelControls(GUIPanel panel) {


        this.panel = panel;
        this.panel.add(lines);
    }
```

then this makes the new panel;

```
public class GUIPanel extends JPanel {

    BufferedImage image;

    public GUIPanel(int width, int height) {

        this.image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics g = this.image.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
        this.setFocusable(true);

    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getSize() {

        return (new Dimension(this.image.getWidth(), this.image.getHeight()));
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {
        Graphics g = graphics.create();
        g.drawImage(this.image, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

ok, here's tabGUI;

```
    private GUIPanel panel;
    private panelControls controls;

    public tabGUI(String title, int width, int height) {

        super(String.format("Title", title));

        this.panel = new GUIPanel(width, height);
        this.controls = new panelControls(this.panel);
        this.getContentPane().add(this.controls, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public GUIPanel getGUIPanel() {
        return (this.panel);
    }
}
```

and this is the main;

```
public class mainGUI implements Runnable {

    private tabGUI tabGui;
    private String title;
    public mainGUI(String title) {

        this.title = title;
        this.tabGui = new tabGUI(this.title, 1110, 700);

    }

    public void setTitle(String title){
        this.tabGui.setTitle(this.title);
    }

    public void run() {

        this.tabGui = new tabGUI(this.title, 1110, 700);
        this.tabGui.setTitle(this.title);
        this.tabGui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.tabGui.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1240, 800));
        this.tabGui.pack();
        this.tabGui.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

//        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        String title = "piece1";
        //put the tab source file to run here
        mainGUI tabGui = new mainGUI(title);
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(tabGui);


    }
}
```

getting this;

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1090)
    at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:410)
    at readtabcode.panelControls.<init>(panelControls.java:15)
    at readtabcode.tabGUI.<init>(tabGUI.java:17)
    at readtabcode.mainGUI.<init>(mainGUI.java:14)
    at readtabcode.mainGUI.main(mainGUI.java:37)
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: you're passing `null` into `panelControls`. Forgot to initialize `GUIPanel` ? Also, Class Names Need To Be Capitalized.

Comment: First of all, you left out `tabGui`, which is where the error is being caused, second, `Graphics g = graphics.create();` is not required and will actually cause you problems (it will consume never ending resources until you're out of memory), third, `panelControls` is completely useless as it stands as it does nothing that could be achieved directly, fourth `g.fillRect(...)` would probably be more efficient than rendering a blank image, but `setBackground(Color)` would achieve the same result...

Comment: Oh, and don't override `getSize`, this will lead you down a slipperly slope of confusion as your application no longer does what you expect it to...you appropriate layout managers and where required, override `getPreferred/Minimum/MaximumSize`

Comment: Is this for 5-string banjo?  Guitar need 6 lines for tablature...one for each string.

Comment: MadProgrammer, how do you know that the error is at TabGUI?

Comment: tabGUI now there, it's for a lute, just hadn't thought about it as I'm a Violist. panelControls will do something soon, lots more stuff!

Comment: for some reason it wasn't happy letting me put this in the constructor of panelControls, so I inserted it into the main under run() and it seems ok. Thanks for your help.